# Adding Edit button to ArcGIS Javascript template?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We've been able to successfully download the Find, Edit, Filter template, customize the configurations, and host it on our own server but here is the issue we are facing now.

We're looking to use this application for our Business License field officers. They stop by a business, check their business license and then classify it one of several different ways. The Business License layer is a point layer. By and large we do not have our address layer separated into units so in a few instances we have many Business License points right on top of each other making the data hard to edit. Not a huge deal from the desktop but if you're using a tablet it's a pain to scroll through 15 different pop-ups to edit the feature you want. As a result we're using the search function to search by business name. Has anyone written code that will create an edit button within the popup once the feature is found from the search box? As it stands now we can search for and zoom to the feature but then you must click the edit button and then reclick the feature you want to edit. Doing this means you have to then scroll through until you find your feature [(link to application](http://gisweb64test.greenvillesc.gov/businesslicenseinspections/s2.html?app=apps2/bli), search for Yankee Candle, click edit button then click back on feature). It's built in as a feature in the default web map (see picture below) but not in any of the apps.

[image]